# replace numbers inside an XML element using xmlValue

Tags: xml, r

I have bunch of numbers

```
preKId_2015 = c(242938L, 339402L, 361888L, 428033L, 442546L, 309790L, 355662L, 
458179L, 465105L, 490383L, 524644L, 526614L, 539453L, 555516L, 
569709L)
```

I have an xml file with some other id values already between the elements

```
<input-id> 
"PreKId"
12344 
33433
23343
93893
23333
</input-id>
```

I am trying to replace these pre-existing values with the values form preKId_2015. I tried

```
 doc <- xmlParseDoc("C:/... ProjectKids/test12.xml")
 nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//input-id")[[1]]
 xmlValue(nodes) =  replace(xmlValue(nodes),xmlValue(nodes),preKId_2015)
```

I get a warning and nothing happens

```
 Warning message:
 In replace(xmlValue(nodes), xmlValue(nodes),preKId_2015) :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Need help

Comment: Actually it's only a warning, which may mean that something did happen.

Comment: I think it's complaining that the second argument to `replace` is not an index.  I think `xmlValue(nodes) =  replace(xmlValue(nodes),TRUE,preKId_2015)` is what you want.

Comment: @Jthorpe, i tried your suggestion I got an error  `Error in `xmlValue<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "242938") : 
  Cannot set the content of a node that is not an XMLInternalTextNode or a node containing a text node
In addition: Warning message:
In replace(xmlValue(nodes), TRUE, preKId_2015) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `removeChildren` before inserting new nodes:

```
doc <- xmlParseDoc("C:/... ProjectKids/test12.xml")
nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//input-id")[[1]]
removeChildren(ns, .all=TRUE)

# as sub-elements
kids <- lapply( preKId_2015, function(x) newXMLNode("id", x ))
addChildren(ns, kids = kids, append = FALSE)

# or insert it as text node:
addChildren(ns, newXMLTextNode(paste(preKId_2015, collapse = "\n")))
```

Comment: your suggestion works, but I get an ouput like this `<input-file>                      <file>339402</file> <file>361888</file> <file>428033</file> <file>442546</file>` how do i get an output without the  tag `<file>....</file>` for each id ?

Comment: This is the parameter - I guess you used "file" instead of "id" in `newXMLNode` function? If you don't want the subelement, use `addChildren(ns, newXMLTextNode(paste(preKId_2015, collapse = "\n")))`

Comment: the `addChildren(ns,...` is working like a charm however. I still have to manually remove old id...the `removeChildren(ns, .all=TRUE)` is not working. :(

Comment: Can you "print" the `ns` right after the `removeChildren`? Is it empty (mine is `<input-id/>`)?

Comment: I did some stupid mistake, I re ran the code again it worked :), i would send you an online beer if I could cheers :)